# Rename [tag:akka-stream] to [tag:akka-streams]

Tags: support, tags

Please rename the tag [akka-stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/akka-stream) to [akka-streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/akka-streams). It is an [API](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.0/scala/stream/stream-introduction.html) that is part of the [akka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/akka) framework which uses the [reactive-streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactive-streams) (note the plural!) interfaces internally.